# Dynamic filter in pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

I'm writing a script which takes a *lyx file* and convert it in an *html file*. *Pandoc* is just one step of the process so I call pandoc from inside my main script.

Some things are better done in a *pandoc filter*, but I need to pass information to the filter. My solution is to generate the `filter.py` on-the-fly including all the information it needs. Am I missing an obvious cleaner way to do it?

Comment: A good way to pass information is via metadata fields.  One can add metadata from the command line via the `--metadata` parameter.

Comment: @Kiuhnm you'll have to be more specific... a filter is a normal program that can read from the filesystem, env variables, the internet, a db... whatever...